# Gitblit LDAP Authentication after Local Authentication

Tags: authentication, ldap, account, gitblit

This is my scenario: We've been working with local users and group on our Gitblit server until today. Today, we've switched to LDAP Authentication And we're having a few difficulties I would like to address:

1. When a user whom already had a local git account now tries to login with his LDAP account, the git overwrites his local user, which is ok, but makes the newly registered LDAP user lose all the groups that the local user had. Can this be remedied so that the local groups that the local account had would be transferred to the LDAP account as well?
2. If I have a user called "John Doe" and he has a Git account called "John_Doe" and an LDAP account called "John.Doe", Would the LDAP account still overwrite the local account or would it create 2 separate accounts?

Comment: 1. Are you using LDAP teams?  I'm not sure if this is a bug or a config issue.
2. "John_Doe" and "John.Doe" are distinct usernames and would be two distinct accounts.

Comment: Yes, we are using both LDAP and local teams that were created before LDAP authentication was implemented.

Answer (score 1):

1. As of Gitblit 1.8.0 there is no configuration setting that would allow taking over local group membership when a local user is overwritten by a LDAP user. When `realm.ldap.maintainTeams`is set to `true`, then teams for a LDAP user are only retrieved from LDAP.
   As a workaround, you would have to mirror the old local teams in LDAP, recreating team membership for LDAP users, or alternatively, add LDAP users back into local teams manually.
2. As James already answered in his comment, these would be two distinct user accounts.